# Resizing the unity side bar on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: unity, unity-2d

How can we resize the unity side bar on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

I would like to make it as small as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial shows you how to do it, http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-unity-2d-resize-launcher.html.

There are 3 files under this directory, `/usr/share/unity-2d/shell/*`. Edit these files using `sudo gedit <file>`:

`Shell.qml`, change:

```
 # before
 width: 65

 # after
 width: 50
```

`common/IconTile.qml`, change:

```
# before
sourceSize.width: 48
sourceSize.height: 48

# after
sourceSize.width: 32
sourceSize.height: 32
```

`launcher/LauncherList.qml`, change:

```
# before
property int tileSize: 54
property int selectionOutlineSize: 65

# after
property int tileSize: 38
property int selectionOutlineSize: 50
```